# java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to get hadoop and hive to run locally on my linux system, but when I run jps, I noticed that the datanode service is missing:

```
vaughn@vaughn-notebook:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
2209 NameNode
2682 ResourceManager
3084 Jps
2510 SecondaryNameNode
```

If I run bin/hadoop datanode, the following error occurs:

```
    17/07/13 19:40:14 INFO datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    17/07/13 19:40:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/07/13 19:40:15 WARN datanode.DataNode: Invalid dfs.datanode.data.dir /home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data : 
    ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: changing permissions of '/home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data': Operation not permitted

        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:646)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2448)
    17/07/13 19:40:15 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
    java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: "/home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data/" 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2448)
    17/07/13 19:40:15 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
    17/07/13 19:40:15 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
    /************************************************************

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at vaughn-notebook/127.0.1.1
```

That directory seems unusual, but I don't think there's anything technically wrong with it. Here are the permissions on the directory:

```
vaughn@vaughn-notebook:/usr/local/hadoop$ ls -ld /home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:14 /home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data
```

I also removed anything in the tmp folder and formatted the hdfs namenode. Here is my hdfs-site file:

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/name</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/cloudera/hdata/dfs/data</value>
 </property>

</configuration>
```

And my core-site file:

```
<configuration>

<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/cloudera/hdata</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

In my googling, I've seen some suggest running "sudo chown hduser:hadoop -R /usr/local/hadoop_store", but when I do that I get the error "chown: invalid user: ‘hduser:hadoop’". Do I have to create this user and group? I'm not really familiar with the process. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What's the user account you are using to start/stop hadoop services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.sudo chown vaughn:hadoop -R /usr/local/hadoop_store

where hadoop is group name. use

> grep vaughn /etc/group

in your terminal to see your group name.

2.clean temporary directories.

3.Format the name node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this did it!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a permission issue, The user which is used to start datanode should have write access in the data node -data directories.

Try to execute the below command before starting datanode service.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/cloudera/hdata/dfs
```

You can also update owner:group using chown command, that's the best option.

**Edit**

If data node start up still fails try to update the file ownership using the below command before starting data node.

```
sudo chown -R vaughn.root /home/cloudera/hdata/dfs
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, sachin. I already did set the permissions on the dfs folder to 777, I think I forgot to mention that. I tried it again just to be sure, and the datanode still does not start.

The account that I use to start the services is called 'vaughn', but I'm not sure how I would use chown in this context.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R /usr/local/hadoop_store`

delete datanode namenode directories in hadoop_store

`stop-dfs.sh` and `stop-yarn.sh`

`hadoop fs namenode -format`

`start-dfs.sh` and `start dfs-yarn.sh`

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

One more possible reason which was in my case: Location of HDFS directory in folder properties shower user name twice i.e. *home/hadoop/hadoop/hdfs* So, I had added the same directory in **hdfs-site.xml**. As a solution, I removed **hadoop/** and changed it to *home/hadoop/hdfs* and this resolved my problem.